# Binary function which searches an item in a sorted list always returns -1

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to search through a sorted list consisting of

```
sortedList=[2,5,7,9,11,17,222]
```

**Issue:** Unfortunately the code I've written consistently returns -1

```
import math

def binarySearch(li, ele):
    lowest = 0
    highest = len(li)-1
    index = -1
    while highest>=lowest and index==-1:
        mid = int(math.floor((highest+lowest)/2.0))
        if li[mid]==ele:
            index = mid
        elif li[mid]<ele:
            highest = mid-1
        else:
            lowest = mid+1

    return index

sortedList=[2,5,7,9,11,17,222]
print(binarySearch(sortedList,11))
```

**Expected Result**:
The return of the index for the given integer in sortedList

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger? Also, I'd suggest using the right function name, as those don't match.

Comment: function name corrected, issue still stands, but thanks @KennyOstrom

Comment: side note: integer division `(hi+lo) // 2`

Comment: Thanks @KennyOstrom made the adjustments and it really was just a simple mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a logical mistake. Just change < to > .

```
while highest>=lowest and index==-1:
    mid = int(math.floor((highest+lowest)/2.0))
    if li[mid]==ele:
        index = mid
    elif li[mid] > ele:  # this line
        highest = mid-1
    else:
        lowest = mid+1
```